# The final mapping would have more than 1 type Error - Intermittent

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am currently observing the below error. Strangely, it worked for the first time, later on I had to an additional field (Tag) to my data and that was the only change I have done and now i get the mapping error. I was not able to figure out the reason behind it and now when i remove the field i added, I still get this error. ELK version - 6.2.3

> [2018-03-23T06:15:30,271][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could
>   not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index",
>   {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"healthccms-2018.03.23", :_type=>"doc",
>   :_routing=>nil}, #],
>   :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"healthccms-2018.03.23",
>   "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"sffsf_HFKJ_sajfkjf6", "status"=>400,
>   "error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Rejecting
>   mapping update to [healthccms-2018.03.23] as the final mapping would
>   have more than 1 type: [my_doc, doc]"}}}}

When i changed my mappings name to doc, i get the below error. I see there is nothing relevant to the error i got and the template i have.

> [2018-03-23T06:46:57,483][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could
>   not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index",
>   {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"healthccms-2018.03.23", :_type=>"doc",
>   :_routing=>nil}, #],
>   :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"healthccms-2018.03.23",
>   "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"gjYcU2IB9pgc1BKZxkks", "status"=>400,
>   "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to
>   parse", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception",
>   "reason"=>"Could not convert [message.index] to boolean",
>   "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Failed
>   to parse value [not_analyzed] as only [true] or [false] are
>   allowed."}}}}}}

Mapping Template:

```
{
  "template": "healthccms-*",
  "settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval": "10s"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_doc": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "message_field": {
            "path_match": "message",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "omit_norms": true
            },
            "match_mapping_type": "string"
          }
        },
        {
          "integers": {
            "match_mapping_type": "long",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "mapping": {
              "type": "text",
              "index": "analyzed",
              "norms": false,
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 1024
                }
              }
            },
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "match": "*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "format": "dateOptionalTime",
          "type": "date"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "host": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "path": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "ETime": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "OverAllStatus": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "Env": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "HostAddress": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "ThresholdDiskSpace": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "Tag": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I see in the documentation that the mapping contains more than 1 type, i actually didn't understand what does that mean. Can someone help me understand what is the issue in the template and how can i overcome it.

Comment: Your type is named my_doc and you are trying to update mapping on doc. So it would be PUT /healthccms.../_mapping/my_doc

Comment: thanks, apart from this, there is one more mistake in my template. corrected it.

Comment: please write which one was the second mistake so this is useful for the others